# Why does my AsyncValidator always return true?

Tags: angular, customvalidator

Why does this always return the error?

```js
export class UserExistsValidatorService implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  validate(control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.userService.existsUser(control.value)
      .pipe(map(exists => (exists === false) ? null : {
         userExists: { valid: false }
       }),
       catchError(() => of(null)));
   }
}
```

This implementation of validating calls a service method which returns an `Observable<boolean>`

```js
existsUser(username: string): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/existsUser`, { username })
      .pipe(map(response => response.userExists === '1'))
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
```

I have verified the service works correctly by subscribing & logging it for a quick test:

```js
this.userService.existsUser(this.registerGrp.controls.username.value)
    .subscribe(exists => { console.log(exists); });
```

this prints true/false as I expect it.

However, my FormGroup.invalid always returns false. It seems that the validator always fires.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Formularmodell bauen
    this.registerGrp = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', this.userExistsValidator],
      password: [''],
      // Confirm-Feld müsste eigentlich nicht auf required geprüft werden
      // confirmPassword: [''],
      confirmPassword: [''],
      xboxName: [''],
      discordName: [''],
      accepted: [false]
    });
}

console.log(this.registerGrp.invalid); // always false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular isn't unwrapping your observable, it's just evaluating the whole `Observable` object, which is always truthy.

The reason why it happens is that you aren't telling Angular that that is an async validator. The [`control` signature](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#control) is able to accept up to 3 parameters: the state, the sync validators list, the async validators list.

In your case, if you don't have sync validators, you can pass `null` as the second parameter:

```
username: ['', null, this.userExistsValidator],
```

Comment: this doesnt work. core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: this.asyncValidator is not a function
    at FormControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:4358)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4311)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:4920)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:9481)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:9541)
    at forms.js:9520
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.js:9515)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:9434)
    at RegisterComponent.ngOnInit (register.component.ts:34)

Comment: Okay, figoured it out :-) it's username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], [this.userExistsValidator]], with another pair of [brackets]